# What version of geth do i need for the merge?

Tags: go-ethereum, hardforks, the-merge

What version of geth do i need for the merge? Will my node with `Vectra (v1.10.20)`
run smoothly after the merge without updating to the latest version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You will need at least [Geth version 1.10.23 (Sentry Omega)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.10.23).

##### https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/08/24/mainnet-merge-announcement

In addition to Geth (an execution layer client), you will also need to run a [consensus layer client](https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/08/24/mainnet-merge-announcement) as in the announcement above, and then authenticate (connect) them as described below.

---

### Install a consensus layer client

https://ethereum.org/en/upgrades/merge/#preparing-for-the-merge

Assuming you are a **Non-validating node operator**, key action items include:

- Install a [consensus layer client](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#consensus-clients) in addition to an [execution layer client](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#execution-clients)
- Authenticate execution and consensus clients with a shared JWT secret so they can securely communicate with one another.

### Authenticating the clients

https://launchpad.ethereum.org/en/merge-readiness/#authenticate

Communication between the execution layer and consensus layer will occur using the Engine API. This is a new set of JSON RPC methods that can be used to communicate between the two client layers.

Instructions for how to set this JWT secret vary depending on the client — node operators should refer to their clients' documentation for instructions about how to generate and configure these.

- [Besu: CLI Syntax engine-jwt-secret](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Reference/CLI/CLI-Syntax/#engine-jwt-secret)
- [Geth: The Merge, EL - CL communication](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/merge#el---cl-communication)
- [Erigon: Authentication API](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon#authentication-api)
- [Lighthouse: Lighthouse Book](https://lighthouse-book.sigmaprime.io/)
- [Nethermind: Running Nethermind Post Merge JwtSecretFile](https://docs.nethermind.io/nethermind/first-steps-with-nethermind/running-nethermind-post-merge#jwtsecretfile)
- [Nimbus: The Nimbus book](https://nimbus.guide/)
- [Prysm: Authenticating Execution Node Connections](https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/execution-node/authentication)
- [Teku: Configure the Java Web](https://docs.teku.consensys.net/en/latest/HowTo/Prepare-for-The-Merge/#3-configure-the-java-web-token)

Answer (score 2):

here is a good writeup for the current situation: https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/08/24/mainnet-merge-announcement/